# Grails synchronize execution of service method

Tags: grails

I am trying to add Files to a (Blog)Post Domain Object.
The file uploader allows to send multiple ajax requests one for each file in parallel.

How can I best take care of the synchronization on the server side?

To avoid:

```
Could not synchronize database state with session    org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another   transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):
```

I am doing this in Grails service with:

```
static scope = "session"
```

This didn't do what I needed.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell for sure what is going wrong.  What types of things is your service doing with Hibernate and do you have current requests potentially interacting with the same data?